# Mapping values and merging dataframes based on multiple column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframes:

df1: dataframe with patient critical notes

```
AREA                      DATE_TIME                 CRITICAL ISSUE NOTES
0013                      11/6/2017 2:25:00 P.M     Nurse attended to the patient 
1121                      10/23/2017 6:43:00 A.M    Completed an ER
1121                      10/2/2017 9:30:00 P.M     Admitted
```

df2: Patient other details

```
ZIP                TIME_NOTED   NAME    OCCUPIED    STATE
4568    10/1/2017 10:04:00 A.M  Chris          Y    NORMAL
1121    10/23/2017 6:43:00 A.M  Nancy          Y    CRITICAL
1121    10/2/2017 9:30:00 P.M   Derek          N    CRITICAL
```

I have to map the records in df2 using DATE_TIME and AREA code from df1 and also retain all other columns in both dataframes. I tried merging on multiple columns but didnt work as expected.

```
new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2,  how='right', left_on=['Date_Time','AREA'], right_on = ['ZIP','TIME_NOTED'])
```

Comment: What is the error you get when you try the `merge`. And what is ENS?

Comment: Looks like `right_on` should be `['TIME_NOTED', 'ZIP']` to stand a chance of matching the `left_on`...

Comment: What @JonClements is saying is that you need to check to order of your right_on and left_on list.  Either put the date column first in both list or second in both list.  Currently, right_on doesn't match left_on and the merge will not work.

Comment: @ScottBoston Tried changing the order. It shows empty values for all columns in df1 after the merge

Comment: Please add the outputs of df1.to_dict() and df2.to_dict() in your question.

Comment: @ScottBoston Sorry, I didnt follow that.

Comment: print(df1.to_dict()) and print(df2.to_dict()) and paste the outputs as update to your question.

Comment: @ScottBoston Data is too large to post here. Even first few lines are more

Comment: How about df1.info() and df2.info()

Comment: @ScottBoston `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 848 entries, 110 to 957
Data columns (total 3 columns):
DATE_TIME                              848 non-null datetime64[ns]
AREA                                   848 non-null object
CRITICAL ISSUE NOTES                   847 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(2)
memory usage: 26.5+ KB`

Comment: df2.info(): `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 604558 entries, 0 to 604557
Data columns (total 22 columns):
ZIP          445885 non-null float64
TIME_NOTED   604558 non-null object
NAME         604558 non-null object
OCCUPIED     604558 non-null object
STATE        604558 non-null object`

Comment: Ah... there's your problem.  I think.  TIME_NOTED is not a datetime dtype like DATE_TIME is in your first dataframe.

Comment: df2['TIME_NOTED'] = pd.to_datetime['TIME_NOTED'] and try your merge again.

Comment: @ScottBoston Tried the same, its NaN again.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the columns in the same order for both left/right_on (area/zip then date time/time noted) it should work. I also changed the merge to an inner, so you just get records with the same zip/area and date time/time noted.

```
new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2,  how='inner', left_on = ['AREA','DATE_TIME'], right_on = ['ZIP','TIME_NOTED'])
```

Another potential solution would be creating an "ID" column and merging on that.

```
df1['ID'] = df1['AREA'].astype(str) + '_' + df1['DATE_TIME'].astype(str)
df2['ID'] = df2['ZIP'].astype(str) + '_' + df2['TIME_NOTED'].astype(str)
```

Now merge on the IDs

```
new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'inner',left_on = ['ID'], right_on = ['ID'])
```

This should yield the same table (with the addition of an ID column).

Comment: `how = 'inner'` resulted in Zero records in the result. And for some reason the after re ordering the columns, it still doesnt work with `how ='right'`. Even after all this discussion, I'm just curious how simple the fix would be.

Comment: How are you creating the dataframes? Because the merge worked properly for me after copying your df examples above and using pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+') to recreate the dataframes.

Comment: Reading from a csv file. I have checked for the datatypes of all the columns on which we need to merge and they are equal. `int` and `datetime64[ns]`

Comment: Strange, it must be a dtype problem. The dates do not appear to be in a typical date time format. Have you tried the ID work around? Or possibly trying to do an .astype() to the columns individually to specify the desired dtype explicitly.